# Send Json files consists of many rows from web server applications to mobile applications and vice versa

Tags: json, google-cloud-messaging, vaadin7, codenameone, amazon-sns

I need to send json files consisting of 10000 rows each to web server(Vaadin application) from mobile application(Native application using codename one) and vice versa. Is there any service which can help me in solving this problem. I am reading [Amazon SNS Push service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html)  and [GCM google service](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) which are useful in sending push notifications(messages).

My question is can i use the above services to serve my need i.e.,large data instead of simple messages or else any service is there to handle big data, pls help me?

Answer (score 1):

The way to upload large files in HTTP/S is mime multipart which is supported by the Java EE servlet API. You need to just use the `MultipartRequest` class and add the data to it. The rest works as a standard connection request in Codename One.

On the server side you can just have a servlet handle such a request. This is covered for photo uploads in this tutorial:

http://udemy.com/build-mobile-ios-apps-in-java-using-codename-one/

Which uses this code for the servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ImageServlet", urlPatterns = {"/image"})
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        String w = request.getParameter("w");
        String h = request.getParameter("h");
        long i = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("i"));
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
            if(w != null) {
                int width = Integer.parseInt(w);
                int height = Integer.parseInt(h);    
                out.write(ImageFile.getThumb(i, width, height));
            } else {
                out.write(ImageFile.getImage(i));
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And this code to upload in the client side:

```
MultipartRequest mp = new MultipartRequest() {
    private long key;
    @Override
    protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream di = new DataInputStream(input);
        key = di.readLong();
    }

    @Override
    protected void postResponse() {
        final Button btn = createImageButton(key, grid, imageList.getSize());
        imageList.addImageId(key);
        grid.addComponent(0, btn);
        if(!animating) {
            animating = true;
            grid.animateLayoutAndWait(400);
            animating = false;
        }
    }
};
mp.setUrl(UPLOAD_URL);
try {
    mp.addData("i", picture, "image/jpeg");
    mp.addArgument("p", "Data;More data");
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(mp);
} catch(IOException err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#payload) has max message size of 4KB.

Hence sending large amounts of data through these systems is not possible. You should use GCM to send a small message to the device indicating that the device should request the large data payload directly from the application server.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand; I would suggest that you consider uploading it as a raw .json file (just like you submit a form that requires a file). Then all filtering and executing happens on the server side. 10000 entries is not that big of a file - so once you uploaded it to your self you are good to good. Try to thinking of a little notification that says when the upload has been completed and another one that says when the execution on the server is completed.